# Executing python script on IIS windows server 2022

Tags: python, windows, iis, server

Following this tutorial https://techexpert.tips/iis/enable-python-iis/ i get an internal server error, executing a simple python script. Where can i find logs for this error? Any hints how i can solve this issue?

Comment: Python web apps (not simple scripts) should be hosted on IIS via HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ The legacy CGI approach was 2 decades old, and nobody should use that any more. If you are studying Python, try to find better resources.

Comment: Internal server error is usually 500 error, you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information.